# Is file specified in .ssh/config/IdentityFile private or public key?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication

If I specify in my ssh config

```
Host myhost
    User myname
    IdentityFile mykey
```

then what is `IdentitfyFile`: private or public key?

Answer (score 6):

The private key. See https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config. It defaults to `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and when you generate a key pair, the public one defaults to `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.

**In case you're interested**: The private key is the one that you, and you alone, have access to. That's the base assumption for its use as an authentication method. When you supply the key via IdentifyFile, it is actually not sent to the remote server. The public-private key pair allows you to *prove* that you have it without sending it, thus keeping it private. Once the server has validated this proof, it will trust that you are the relevant user. In order to do this proof, it requires that the server knows the public key that matches the private on, and that's why you put these in `.ssh/authorized_keys` (or similar) on the server. And you could potentially use the same public key on many server.

Comment: Apparently there are some cases where it can be the public key: https://serverfault.com/a/599565/836715