# Can't gain SSH access: "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: linux, ssh, macos

I usually use [Termius](https://termius.com/) to SSH my Debian server from Mac, which so far works great.
Now simply being curious, I try to use built-in Mac SSH client, no third party involved.

This is the content of **~/.ssh/config** on my Mac:

```
Host stalingrad
    Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    User root
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/digital_ocean_id_rsa.pub
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

I've checked that my Mac's **~/.ssh/digital_ocean_id_rsa.pub** matches with my Debian box's **/root/.ssh/authorized_keys**

Also run these command on VPS:

```
$ chmod 700 /root/.ssh
$ chmod 600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys 
$ /etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

OK, let's try ssh:

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I got these:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_ed25519 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_xmss 
debug1: Will attempt key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,webauthn-sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: publickey-hostbound@openssh.com=<0>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/andre/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: Permission denied (publickey).
```

And this is the content of **/var/log/auth.log** on the VPS:

```
Oct 31 14:58:29 stalingrad sshd[249851]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Oct 31 14:58:29 stalingrad sshd[249851]: Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 52960
Oct 31 14:58:50 stalingrad sshd[253607]: Connection closed by authenticating user root yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy port 60773 [preauth]
Oct 31 14:58:59 stalingrad sshd[254173]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Oct 31 14:58:59 stalingrad sshd[254173]: Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 57792
Oct 31 14:59:27 stalingrad sshd[254174]: Received disconnect from yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy port 60774:11: Normal Shutdown [preauth]
Oct 31 14:59:27 stalingrad sshd[254174]: Disconnected from authenticating user root yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy port 60774 [preauth]
Oct 31 14:59:29 stalingrad sshd[254176]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Oct 31 14:59:29 stalingrad sshd[254176]: Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 34386
Oct 31 14:59:49 stalingrad sshd[254177]: Connection closed by authenticating user root yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy port 60777 [preauth]
Oct 31 14:59:59 stalingrad sshd[254180]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Oct 31 14:59:59 stalingrad sshd[254180]: Connection closed by xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 39216
```

Seems like ssh didn't read the specified private key file, which is **digital_ocean_id_rsa**. Instead, it tried to read a bunch of private key files which name started with "id_". What's wrong here?

Comment: As you realized, it does not appear your SSH is looking at the specified private key.  Try to see if either of these commands get you any further:  `ssh -i ~/.ssh/digital_ocean_id_rsa.pub root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and `ssh stalingrad`

Comment: `ssh -i /Users/andre/.ssh/digital_ocean_id_rsa root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` works. Hmm...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any ssh working with the public key as the IdentityFile

Ensure you utilize the private key filename and not the public key filename.

```
Host stalingrad
    Hostname xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    User root
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/digital_ocean_id_rsa
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

[Is file specified in .ssh/config/IdentityFile private or public key?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/516207/is-file-specified-in-ssh-config-identityfile-private-or-public-key)

Comment: I tried that, and ran ssh again: `ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. The same error still happens. But `ssh -i /Users/andre/.ssh/digital_ocean_id_rsa root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` works fine. OK I'm confused

Comment: When you use `root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` as the target, you're not using the target stanza in the `.ssh/config` file, so it's trying to use your default identity files.  You have to use the name of the host as given in the stanza identification, so `root@stalingrad` - neither the IP nor the FQDN will work in this case. Since you specify `User root`, you can probably simple `ssh stalingrad` and the client will pick up the user and FQDN from the configuration stanza.

Comment: @John It works. OK I learn something new today :)